# LT1019 voltage reference output 5V to 3.3V

Tags: voltage-divider, voltage-reference

I have [LT1019ACN8-5](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1019fd.pdf) IC output is 5V. I am using this IC to get Vref 3.3 for the ADS8320. is it ok if i use a voltage divider to the output pin to regulate 5v to 3.3v. Is it acceptable ?

Comment: Is your load absolutely constant?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Load --> I am using output to feed Vref of the ADS8320 [http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads8320.pdf] IC

Comment: Kind of a waste of a nice reference.  The errors you get from the divider resistors will swamp the accuracy of the reference.

Comment: also i need to know difference between shunt and series type of these voltage reference ICs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference input of the ADS8320 draws varying current depending on the sample rate, like many ADC converters without reference buffers.

[image]

At, say, 25uA, a source resistance of only 2 ohms will result in 1 lsb of change in reading due to the reference current. It's usually best to use a buffer that has low noise output. Sometimes this is surprisingly expensive to do right, although fortunately it's only 16 bits.

Comment: then LT1790-3.3V 60uA [http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/6656fc.pdf] will be suit for this.  or LT6656-3.3V High Output Drive Current: 5mA Min
[http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1790fc.pdf] right?

Comment: Both those are pretty good. The 2nd one has about 1/3 the noise (+/- 0.3 LSB vs. +/1 LSB). Keep in mind the dropout voltage spec.